# WCF SOAP Service testing - how to test directly from browser

Tags: c#, json, wcf, soap

I have a WCF SOAP service with the following method:

```
[OperationContract]

string GetDetails(string param1);
```

Method `GetDetails` returns JSON string. I tested the method and it works as expected. When I run the service with WCF Test Client and pass in a parameter, it spits out a string in JSON format. But if I call the service from browser:

> http://ServerName/projectName/ServiceName.svc/GetDetails/12345

I get an error `Resource not found`.

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: To test WCF services (if it's SOAP) you can use a Chrome plugin called Boomerang. To get the WSDL if your service you need to put this URL into a new service in Boomerang: http://ServerName/projectName/ServiceName.svc?wsdl. It will then be able to create a client for all of your [OperationContract]s

Comment: SOAP services are not like REST services, so generally speaking you wouldn't test them in the browser, you'd test them with WCFTestClient, SoapUI, a client you write, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigating to a URL in a browser performs a GET request on that resource. SOAP methods all use POST.

If you would test this with a program like Fiddler or Postman, you can test the different kind of HTTP methods like GET or POST. If you would perform a GET on your URL in fiddler you would get the same result as in the browser. Performing a POST would give you the same result as with the WCF Test Client.